# Geany: How to increase the font size of plugin MultiTerm in Geany text editor?

Tags: geany, geany-plugin

I have been using geany text editor quite a lot.
I have activated the plugin MultiTerm, however, the problem is the font is too small and I can't increase the font size.

Attempts:
1. select the text in MultiTerm and Cmd +
2. select the text in MultiTerm and go to View then choose Increase Font.

I searched the preference options and I was unable to find the solution.

The screenshot looks like this:[image]

I need a magnifier to see what the letters are there in the Multi Terminal to read them, but I assume that was not the purpose of the plugin.
If anybody has any idea the suggestion will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to plugin [documentation](https://plugins.geany.org/multiterm.html) the fontsize can be changed in plugins config file:

`~/.config/geany/plugins/multiterm/multiterm.conf`

You can tweak also background and font color.

sample from file:

```
[shell=default]

# This will be the tabs default tab label and won't change unless
# track_title is set to true.
name=Default Shell

# This is the command to fork in the VTE, leave blank for default shell
command=sh

# Make the tab's label track the VTE title
track_title=true

# Background color, foreground color and font for the VTE
bg_color=#ffffff
fg_color=#000000
font=Monospace 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Why all the hassle !! Simply open VIEW and select ZOOM IN as many times as you like till you get the size you want. It prints the size on the screen. For instance, before doing this it prints 51 lines to the page, after zooming in a few times it prints 42 lines - depending on how many times you zoom in.
martin